# Get height and width from TableLayoutPanel cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cell, tablelayoutpanel

I need to find out the height and width of a cell in which I placed a button. RowStyles and ColumnStyles are both set to Percent, TableLayoutPanel's Dock is Fill, as well as the button's Dock.

```
TableLayoutPanelCellPosition pos = tableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(button1);
int width = tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths()[pos.Column];
int height = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRowHeights()[pos.Row];
```

But it doesn't work. I get the following error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in < my program name.exe >
>
> Additional information: Index outside of bounds of array."

I think the problem is because my application is for .NET 3.5 (and can't get any higher).
How do I get the the height and width of the cell, then?

Comment: use `GetPositionFromControl ` instead of `GetCellPosition` and tell us the result

Comment: try to debug what returned tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths(). I think this exception is thrown because pos.column is greater than the boundary of tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths() array. Same with rows.

Comment: are you sure that `button1` is in `tableLayoutPanel1`? if not you get -1 for `pos.Column` and `pos.Row` and it leads to `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `button1` is not in `tableLayoutPanel1`.
so calling `tableLayoutPanel1.GetCellPosition(button1)` result in (-1,-1) and 
`int width = tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths()[-1];` absolutely throws `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Turned out the button was inside a panel, it worked when I tested it against the panel rather than the button. What a silly mistake.